# Saving ad retrieving images from MS SQL Server using Hibernate - using the image type

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am using `Hibernate`. I have mapped my column nIcon `VARBINARY(MAX)` in my object as the following

```
    @Column(columnDefinition="binary")
     public byte[] getNicon() {
      return this.nicon;
    }
```

The method getByteArrayFromFile() is used to get the bytes from an image file, which I successfully write to the database.

```
    public static byte[] getByteArrayFromFile(String absoluteFilePath) {
            byte [] byteArray = null;
            File file = new File(absoluteFilePath);
            byteArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
            try {
                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                 fileInputStream.read(byteArray);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                logger.error(getStackTrace(e));
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error(getStackTrace(e));
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                if(fileInputStream != null) {
                     try {
                        fileInputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        logger.error(getStackTrace(e));
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return byteArray;
        }
```

The method  getFileFromByteArray() is used to write the image file from the byte array that I retrieve from the database.

```
        public static boolean getFileFromByteArray(String fileName, byte [] byteArray) {
            boolean isSuccessful = false;
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
            try {
                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                fileOutputStream.write(byteArray);
                isSuccessful = true;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                logger.error(getStackTrace(e));
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error(getStackTrace(e));
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (fileOutputStream !=null) {
                    try {
                        fileOutputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        logger.error(getStackTrace(e));
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return isSuccessful;
        }
```

My problem is that I am using binary to store the file. I would like to use the `IMAGE` type in `MS SQL Server`.

I know that the `Hibernate` mapping `@LOB` can be used to store the image as IMAGE type.
BUT I am having problems while writing the bytes back to file.

Comment: Why do you want to the image datatype? It is deprecated. You should instead use varbinary(max). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Comment: Hi. The client's database already uses the IMAGE datatype.

Comment: So change it to varbinary.